# How to tell google analytics that I am a bot?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-analytics, bots

I recently wrote a tool that checks if certain requests on a web page are fired. For example is jquery from a google server loaded when I visit StackOverflow? The tool is based on [webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) and a chrome browser.

The tool works like a charm but it also generates google analytics traffic that should not be there.

Is there a possibility to tell Google that the tool is a bot and should not be counted? All solutions I found focus on the page under test and how to not collect data via Google. I need a solution that works without changing the website's code.

Comment: This sounds like a question for google... how do you know they don't want bots counted in their traffic?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the easiest way would be to send a custom user agent string along and filter by that via a view filter.

Untested, but I think if you use the same user agent string as the Google crawler I'm pretty certain it will be filtered out automatically (after all Google should be smart enough to filter their own crawler). [According to this page](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Googlebot) the Google crawler UA always contains the string "Googlebot" (else youD have to go through your server logs to find a likely UA string).

Answer (score 1):

We solved our problem with a chrome extension. That extension redirects all requests against the google collect endpoint to example.com. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

It sounds interesting to know about a tool which `checks if certain requests on a web page are fired` for e.g. `jquery from a google server loaded`.

Practically, there is a lot of difference when a page e.g. StackOverflow.com is opened Manually (through keying in the URL manually) and when `chromedriver` exe is used to initiate the new Google Chrome session.

As an example, manually when we open a new Google Chrome session, the command line parameters which gets passed along with `chrome.exe` are **`--flag-switches-begin`** and **`--flag-switches-end`** only.

But when we try to use `chromedriver` exe, we generally take help of `ChromeOptions` class and `DesiredCapabilities` class to add various config parameters to the Google Chrome session. Apart from all these one parameter is added i.e. **`--test-type=webdriver`**.

Hence any website when accessed by `chromedriver` exe is always aware that it's a **`Automated Bot`**.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.